# Changing CSS on Datepicker via jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am returning some data server-side and need to cycle through the dates of a calendar and adjust the CSS. I am currently doing something like this:

```
$.post("GetMeSomeData", { year: theYear, month: theMonth }, function(data) {
            //cycle through the dates and address the CSS appropriately
            var i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $('.ui-datepicker-calendar td a:exactly(' + data[i]['d'] + ')')
                    .css({ backgroundColor: 'blue' });
            }

        });

  $.expr[":"].exactly = function (el, i, m) {
        var s = m[3];
        if (!s) return false;
        return eval("/^" + s + "$/i").test($(el).text());
    };
```

The background of the individual days are not changing. Is there a better way to do this or am I missing something? Ideally, I'd like to just use addClass() as I'm fairly certain I need to use '!important' to override things on the calendar.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the pseudo-selector `:exactly`. Googled it and couldn't find it. Did you maybe mean to use `:nth-child`?

Comment: Sorry--I meant to include that function... here it is

Comment: :exactly is a function that I neglected to put in my code snippet above. I've included it now for you to see.